# spamassassin --lint and spamc return different scores

Tags: email, spamassassin, spam-filter

I'll keep this short and sweet.

`spamassassin --lint -D < email_message_to_test.eml`
Returns:
`[22154] dbg: check: is spam? score=4.205 required=5`
Which is an entirely reasonable score, it is in fact what I'm looking for.

While
`spamc -R < email_message_to_test.eml`
Returns:
`Content analysis details:   (-0.7 points, 5.0 required)`
Which is way to low!

Looking for why, and how to fix it.

System info:
FreeBSD 7.2
SpamAssassin version 3.2.5
 running on Perl version 5.8.9
No previous installs.

Thanks!
Chance

**EDIT**
This is embarrassing. It appears that --lint *always returns a score of 4.205*, no matter what email I feed it. I was misunderstanding what --lint did, and since I was looking for something wrong I jumped on it.

Both answers make good points, and even though I'd love to delete this :) I'm leaving
it up in case someone else wonders the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you setup some local user_prefs rules for SpamAssassin?

If so, have you set allow_user_rules in your local.cf?

Comment: I think Phil is right.  Start spamd with --nouser-config option and then run spamc again

Comment: This is embarrassing. It appears that  `--lint` always returns a score of 4.205, no matter what email I feed it. I think I was misunderstanding what `--lint` did, and since I was looking for something wrong I jumped on it.

Comment: ahh lol, yeh. I missed that too --lint checks syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have spamassassin running in a jail, using different config files than in your test?

If so, ensure that /etc/spamassassin in the jail contains the same files as /etc/spamassassin outside of the jail.